# CN1: Scrolling not working on MultiButton

Tags: java, codenameone

So, I have a form with a multibutton, but the scrolling is not working.
    I already tried it with a normal button, but I need the secondTextLine

```
MultiButton mbProducts = new MultiButton(product);
            //Produkte in Detail (Form)
            ProdukteDetailForm produkteDetailForm = new ProdukteDetailForm();
            //Backbutton
            Button btnBack = new Button("Zurück");
            btnBack.addActionListener(b -> {
                new ProdukteForm().show();
            });

            //ProductDetails
            Container conProdukteDetail = new Container(BoxLayout.y());
            ...
            conProducts.add(mbProducts);
        }
        this.add(conProducts);
        initGuiBuilderComponents(resourceObjectInstance);
```

Is there an alternative? Or a better way to solve that problem? As I said, I need the secondLine from the Multibutton

Comment: Scrolling doesn't have anything to do with `MultiButton` it looks like you used a GUI builder form in some way. What's the scrollable container here?

Comment: I used the BoxLayout with Y Axis. What should I use instead?

Comment: Container conOrders = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

Comment: But is that scrollable on the Y axis? Is the parent container scrollable? Did you make it scrollable in the GUI builder? Only one container in the hierarchy should be scrollable...

Comment: conOrders is the parent container and I added `conProducts.setScrollableY(true);`. I also marked it scrollable in the GUI already...

Comment: That sounds like you created a nested scrollable container. Only one container should be scrollabel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using this code:

```
    Container conProducts = new Container(new BorderLayout());
    Container conBorder = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    conProducts.setScrollableY(true);

    ...

    conBorder.add(mbProducts);
    conProducts.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, conBorder);
```